# javascript tab key problem? in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why doesnt work this code one safari,chrome and internet explorer.. Only works with Opera and Firefox...

```
  $("#txtAd").keypress(function (e) {


    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code == 9) {

        $("#txtSoyad").val('');

    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery abstracts that so you don't have to :)

> To determine which character was entered, examine the event object that is passed to the handler function. While browsers use differing properties to store this information, jQuery normalizes the `.which` property so you can reliably use it to retrieve the character code.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/).

Use `e.which`, no need to use `||` short circuit evaluation trick.

Though in saying that, your code [*did* work for me in Chrome 10](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/mnTpc/).

Are you sure `$("#txtSoyad")` is a valid selector, and has selected what you want? Output the `length` property, if you don't see `1`, it isn't selecting it correctly.

Comment: @psygnosis Yes. It works in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/mnTpc/). If you can create a fiddle with it not working, I can look at your code and tell you what is wrong.

Comment: it's okay.. I can do with focus event.. Browsers has already tabbed :):)   $("#txtSoyAd").focus(function(){
               clear the val();

});